# error al acceder a la segunda matriz js

Tags: javascript, json

tengo una consulta; necesito acceder al segundo **Types** del archivo json:

```
          [
{
    "name": "Pikachu",
    "tier": "Tier 1",
    "canBeShiny": true,
    "types": [
        {
            "name": "electric",
            "image": "img/types/electric.png"
        }
    ],
    "combatPower": {
        "normal": {
            "min": 493,
            "max": 536
        },
        "boosted": {
            "min": 616,
            "max": 670
        }
    },
    "boostedWeather": [
        {
            "name": "rainy",
            "image": "img/weather/rainy.png"
        }
    ],
    "image": 

   "img/pokemon_icons/pokemon_icon_pm0025_01_pgo_winter2020.png"
},
{
    "name": "Alolan Sandshrew",
    "tier": "Tier 1",
    "canBeShiny": true,
    "types": [
        {
            "name": "ice",
            "image": "img/types/ice.png"
        },
        {
            "name": "steel",
            "image": "img/types/steel.png"
        }
    ],
    "combatPower": {
        "normal": {
            "min": 688,
            "max": 739
        },
        "boosted": {
            "min": 860,
            "max": 924
        }
    },
    "boostedWeather": [
        {
            "name": "snowy",
            "image": "img/weather/snowy.png"
        }
        ],
      "image": "img/pokemon_icons/pokemon_icon_027_61.png"
      },
]
```

Al primero logro llamarlo de este modo:
${post.types[0].name} y se muestra sin problema alguno, cuando intento llamar al segundo simplemente no me aparece, hay algunos **types** que solo tienen un name y una imagen.

el codigo con el cual intento llamarlo es el siguiente:

${post.types[1].name}

pero no lo reconoce

ayuda por favor!

dejo el codigo, el cual me estuvieron ayduando a realizarlo aqui en este grupo:

```
   const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   const url = '/raids.json';
     request.open("GET", url);
      request.send();

    request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
   const posts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
     posts.forEach((post) => {
     if (post.tier == "Tier 1") { 
      document.getElementById("raid1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
       <div class="ranking_item">
                    <div class="ranking_img ${post.types[0]}">
                    <img src="${post.image}">
                        <div class="ranking_name">
                        <img  src=${post.canBeShiny ? "imagen/iconos/shiny_white.png" : 
              "imagen/iconos/no-shiny-icon.png"} alt="shiny"> 
                        <img src="${post.types[0].image}">
                        <img src="${post.types[1].image}">
                            <span>${post.name}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ranking_info">
                        <div class="ranking_name" style="display: none;">
                            <span>${post.name}</span>
                        </div>
                        <span><strong>Potenciado</strong><img 
          src="${post.boostedWeather[0].image}"></span>
                         <p><strong>CP ${post.combatPower.boosted.min} - 
         ${post.combatPower.boosted.max}  </strong></p>
                        
                        <span>Normal</span>
                        <div class="ranking_rapido">
                            
                            <div>
                                <span>CP ${post.combatPower.normal.min} - 
                ${post.combatPower.normal.max} </span>
                            </div>
                            <span>  </span>
                        </div>
                           
                    </div>
                </div>`
         );
       }
```

espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano, Feliz Navidad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como es un array sería mejor usar un `for`, pero tú lo tienes dentro de un literal template, así que mejor usar un `map`

```
document.getElementById("raid1").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
       <div class="ranking_item">
                    <div class="ranking_img ${post.types[0]}">
                    <img src="${post.image}">
                        <div class="ranking_name">
                        <img  src=${post.canBeShiny ? "imagen/iconos/shiny_white.png" : 
              "imagen/iconos/no-shiny-icon.png"} alt="shiny"> 
                        ${post.types.map(t => '<img src="' + t.image + '">')}
                        <span>${post.name}</span>

//El resto del código
```

Comment: gracias por responder, Yussed, si veo 2 objetos, pero no muestra las imagenes.  <img src="[object Object]"> "," <img src="[object Object]">  eso es lo que obtengo.

Comment: Edité el código, vuelve a probar

Comment: Genial, eres un crack! gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: De nada , me alegro haber podido ayudarte